# pip install the latest version

Tags: python, django, pip

I am new to python and django. In my requirements\common.txt I have the following line with version:

`django-simple-captcha==0.5.*`

the problem is that when I run `pip install -r requirements\common.txt`, as I have version 0.5.3 of that package, it wouldn't update it to latest version (0.5.6), only `pip --upgrade requirements\common.txt` would upgrade to latest version. Is there anyway to modify `common.txt` file so running `pip install` installs the latest version?

I am asking because this file is going to be used by a couple of developers and if they have for example version 0.5.3 of that package already, it would'nt upgrade it and there are lots of packages needing upgrade.

tnx

Comment: Yes, by removing the `==...` By default, pip installs the latest version, but here you pin it to a specific one.

Comment: what if I want the latest minor version?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem would removing `==...` mean that any version of `django-simple-captcha` would meet the requirement and `--upgrade` would be required to actually upgrade the currently installed version? OP was asking how they could force the latest version with `pip install -r`, wouldn't that require a specific pin, e.g. `==0.5.6`

Answer (score 59):

### `-U` or `--upgrade` will update listed packages

**Example:**

```bash
$ pip install -U django-simple-captcha 
# OR
$ pip install --upgrade django-simple-captcha
```

### pip3

```bash
$ pip3 install -U django-simple-captcha 
# OR
$ pip3 install --upgrade django-simple-captcha
```

> pip3 with `sudo` (to install system-wide, this may be required in some cases)

```bash
$ sudo pip3 install -U django-simple-captcha 
# OR
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade django-simple-captcha
```

Answer (score 6):

Just remove `==0.5.*` and the latest available version of `django-simple-captcha` for your OS will be installed if available.

---

To view the current installed version use:

```
pip show django-simple-captcha
```

---

> *what if I want the latest minor version?*

You can try:

```
pip install "package>=0.2,<0.3"
```

---

Here's a [`pip` Cheatsheet](http://dcjtech.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Pip-Cheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: what if I want the latest minor version?